# How can i overlap list item on each other in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, overlap, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

I want to implement this ui.
How can i overlap post list item on each other in android jetpack compose?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using a Column or a LazyList to display the items, you can use the verticalArrangement parameters with a negative spacedBy space.

```
LazyColumn(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy((-32).dp)
) {
    // Put the items to overlap here
}
```

[spacedBy() doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#spacedBy(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp))

Comment: thanks a lot! you're a man.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Box](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#:%7E:text=Use%20Box%20to%20put%20one,layout%20that%20suits%20your%20app.) to put one element on top of another.

Also, read official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/documentation)

Comment: Can you explain how to do this? I still can't find an example.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Box`

sample :

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
     Image(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {} //Image1
     Image(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {} //Image2
}
```

In the above example, Image2 will cover the Box's maxSize. Image1 will be beneath Image2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Bagadeshkumar R's answer, you can place Spacer with height that is `spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))`, attribute between image 1 and 2, for image 1 to be partially visible.